# Nextflow - How to pass the yaml format input file from an argument to channel as a list

Tags: python, unix, groovy, yaml, nextflow

How to pass the `yaml` format input file from an argument to a channel `samples` as a list? Appreciate if any nextflow function or simple solution to make the channel `samples` works!

```
$ nextflow run main.nf \
   -config nextflow.config \
   --input_list s3://my-bucket/params.yml \
   --publish_dir ./output
```

`--input_list s3://my-bucket/params.yaml`

```
samples:
-
 biosample_id: WGS001
 bam: WGS001.bam
-
 biosample_id: WGS0002
 bam: NWGS0002.bam
```

The given below channel `samples` code works well with `-params-file s3://my-bucket/params.yaml` but I need to use with an argument `input_list` for a reason where I can't use with `-params-file`

```
// input_list = "s3://my-bucket/params.yaml"


Channel
    .fromList( params.samples )
    .ifEmpty { ['biosample_id': params.biosample_id, 'bam': params.bam] }
    .set { samples }


Channel
    samples.branch { rec ->
    ....


Channel
    samples.map { it.biosample_id }
    ....
```

The follwoing code works

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper

params.inputs_list = "inputs.yaml"

workflow {    
    inputs = new YamlSlurper().parse(file(params.inputs_list))

    Channel
        .fromList(inputs['samples'])
        .ifEmpty { ['biosample_id': params.biosample_id, 'aln': params.aln] }
        .set { samples }
```

Comment: parse the yml and extract the samples list..?

Comment: yes, with preserving the current method channel `sample` or with minimal changes would be good.

The channel `samples` method in my workflow works in commandline with `-params-file params.yml` but I couldn't run it from nftower dashboard which is one of my requirement.


LImitation of pasting the large size of input (eg. 10k samples list) file as json/yaml in the the nftower dashboard under "pipeline parameter" which is equivalent to the Nextflow `-params-file` option. Here I want to pass the input file as an arg `input_list` to overcome the character limitation.

Comment: @Steve would you able to give any comment? thanks

Comment: The [YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) format looks completely different from the [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) format. The [officially recommended extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for files containing YAML documents has been `.yaml` since at least September 2006. Please catch up.

Answer (score 1):

The follwoing code works

```
import groovy.yaml.YamlSlurper

params.inputs_list = "inputs.yaml"

workflow {    
    inputs = new YamlSlurper().parse(file(params.inputs_list))

    Channel
        .fromList(inputs['samples'])
        .ifEmpty { ['biosample_id': params.biosample_id, 'aln': params.aln] }
        .set { samples }
```